# How do you create a reference to an array at a certain address?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address, memory-mapping

In C++, it is possible to create variables that are references to memory addresses.

```cpp
volatile uint8_t& PPUSTATUS = *(volatile uint8_t*)0x2000;
```

This can be useful for things like memory-mapped I/O or hardware reserved memory regions, especially for embedded systems.
You can even create pointers to memory regions.

```cpp
volatile uint8_t*& FDS_WAV = *((volatile uint8_t**)0x4040);
```

However, is it possible to create a reference to an array at a memory address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
uint8_t(&FDS_WAV)[64] = (uint8_t(&)[64])(*(uint8_t**)0x4040);
```

This will create an array of `64` `uint8_t` at address `0x4040`.
`&FDS_WAV` will return `0x00004040`, and `sizeof(FDS_WAV)` will return `64`.